# App is ideal eventhough Allocated memory size continuously increasing in android

Tags: android

I don't understand why Allocated memory size is increasing and reach till 132mb and then crash application.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have memory leak in your app.
[Leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) is really good and easy to use library for finding those kinds of problems.